# How to include dependency as a .jar in resources with gradle?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to share a dependency between multiple jars. My solution to this would be to include the dependency as a .jar in each one and then load the most up to date one at runtime (in order to not have multiple identical shaded versions, and to include resources from that dependency).

Essentially, I'm trying to make the compiled jar include `dependency.jar` as a resource - how can I achieve this with gradle? Or is there a better way of accomplishing this? I don't want to pull the latest version of the dependency .jar from a remote server as this has to work offline.

Comment: You could publish the dependency with gradle to your local maven repo and depend on it in the other projects by it's maven GAV coordinates. Or did you mean that you want to update from one version to a more recent version of the same dependency while the dependent program is currently running?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of adding a dependency to your project without Gradle accessing a remote repository is to simply add the [file as a dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:file_dependencies) directly:

```
dependencies{
    implementation(files("/path/to/myJar.jar"))
}
```

If you only want to stay offline you can run Gradle with the "offline" command line switch when you are offline. See the [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dynamic_versions.html#sec:controlling_dependency_caching_command_line).

To share across multiple modules you can declare the same file dependency in each module's build file.

Any attempt to compare versions between modules and/or load a JAR at runtime sounds excessively difficult to me.

Comment: No, i'm not trying to depend on a local jar, im trying to include that jar as a resource

Comment: I thought you wanted to access it offline?! Then it will automatically be a local jar.

Comment: Maybe I should have worded it better - it needs to work offline at runtime, not at compile time

Comment: Ah, so you want a fat jar? This looks to be Gradle's recommended way https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example